# Should I create a new MVC 4 Model or use existing one with redundant properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have for example the following MVC Model.

```
public class Fruits
{
  public int FruitId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Type {get;set;}
  public double Price {get;set;}
  public int InStock {get;set;}
  public bool BulkDiscount {get;set;}
  public string PhotoUrl {get;set;}
  public string Url {get;set;}

  public List<Fruits> SimilarFruits {get;set;}
}
```

This model is used to populate a page with the relevant data which is fine.  However, now I want to get a list of Fruits that users purchased that were similar to the current fruit.

I can write the database query to get the data which is fine.  But is the best way for me to re-use the class Fruits even though I'm only interested in the properties

```
public string Name {get;set;}
public string PhotoUrl {get;set;}
public string Url {get;set;}
```

So I could create a list of Fruits like

```
List<Fruits> SimilarFruitList = new List<Fruits>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the same class for now. An additional class would just be bloat at this point.

Only create a new class when you need to add properties that are specific to the data you are returning.

Comment: Even though I'm only use 3 of the possible 8 properties ?

Comment: Personally I don't think it's a problem. You're still returning Fruit (as opposed to vegetables) so I think the code still displays your intent. Also I've seen project with lots of slightly different Models and ViewModels; The large number of classes just introduces a sense of complexity that isn't necessaryily there.

Comment: You could argue on the other hand that the unused properties could confuse another developer. In that case you could have a base Fruit class with the common properties and then inherit that for any classes that require additional properties.